# Change the date format of date picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker

I would like to change the format of like the image attached

[image: date view picker]

from YYYY/MM/DD to dd/MMM hh:min a but unfortunately i cannot do that

Here is my work in view controller 3

```
#import "ViewController3.h"

@interface ViewController3 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController3

@synthesize text;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [self.text setInputView:datePicker];
    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,doneBtn, nil]];
    [self.text setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];

}

-(void)ShowSelectedDate
{   NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM hh:min a"];
    self.text.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [self.text resignFirstResponder];
}
    @end
```

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Use `UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime`

Comment: So you are asking when the user selects a date you want to show it in a different format in textfield??

Comment: any examples of UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime ?

Comment: i mean i would like to choose the month, date and time in the picker instead of YYYY/MM/DD just do not know how to change it

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set up your date formatter in the original date format, and then convert the result to the new date format.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/DD"];
NSString *originalDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM hh:mm a"];
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:origianalDateString];
self.text.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]];
```